# No class matches the given query

Tags: python, django, get, http-status-code-404

I tried to create my first simple app but i have a problem on my way. When i go through a link http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ i have a next error message:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/
/polls/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Django Version: 1.10.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
/polls/index.html
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/alenasanina/djangoenv/bin/mysite',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Oct 2016 21:48:49 +0300
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/alenasanina/djangoenv/bin/mysite/polls/views.py in index
    return render(request, '/polls/index.html', context) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg/django/shortcuts.py in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg/django/template/loader.py in render_to_string
        template = get_template(template_name, using=using) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg/django/template/loader.py in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Next i go through the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1 and here is another error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/
Raised by:  polls.views.detail
No Question matches the given query.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.`enter code here`
```

my models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name='polls'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Choice, Question


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, '/polls/index.html', context)
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
def vote(reqeust, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render (request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes +=1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

results.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

detail.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{%  url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{%  endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

guys, please, help me. I know that it could be very simple to solve but i'm new in Python.

Versions:
Django 1.10.2
Python 3.5

Comment: This looks like a data issue, not an application bug. Check your db and see if there is a poll with id 1

Comment: yeah, that was a problem with id! It was 2 instead of 1!

Answer (score 0):

The path to your templates file `'/polls/index.html'` is probably incorrect. You may have to remove the first / and may the 'polls/' also.